# Spring Boot default auto-configuration based on property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-autoconfiguration

I want to apply the default spring security auto-configuration based on a property from `application.yml`. I thought I first exclude the auto-configuration class and then add it as an import to my configuration class that is conditional on that property:

**MyApplication.class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**ApplicationProperties.class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapplication")
public class ApplicationProperties {

  private boolean security;
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
---
myapplication:
  security: true
```

**SecurityConfig.class:**

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapplication", name = "security", havingValue = "true")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ....
}
```

The `SecurityAutoConfiguration` class never gets imported though:

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

How do I achieve the desired outcome then?

**UPDATE**

Interestingly enough, if I do exactly the same with `KafkaAutoConfiguration.class` it works as I expect - all Kafka beans get loaded and autoconfigured.

```
   KafkaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaAdmin matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaConsumerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaProducerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaProducerListener matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListener; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

Exclusions:
-----------
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one of these to your classes:

This one if you want to make that class work if you `SET THE VALUE OF IT` and `IT IS TRUE`.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapplication", value = "secured", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
```

This one if you want to make that class work if you `DO NOT SET THE VALUE IN THE YAML FILE` or `IT IS SET BUT THE THE VALUE IS FALSE`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapplication", value = "secured", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
```

So for example if you want to use the spring security for your project but sometimes you want to turn it off by setting the value of `myapplication.secured` then you will have a classes like:

Your project will use this class in case you don't want security (myapplication.secured can be missing or set to false):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapplication", value = "secured", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
public class NoSpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

And your project will use this only if the `myapplication.enabled=true` is in your application.yaml file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapplication", value = "secured", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecuritz extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: The `matchIfMissing` attribute doesn't help, but thanks to your code I was able to spot the missing element: I forgot to add the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to my configuration class. Now it works as expected. :)